# laravel component not displayed after replacing two other components

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-blade

i am working on a laravel 10 project (following the laravel 8 from scratch in laracasts series ) where i render posts on the front page i created two components (manually by creating two files on the components directory)to replace a redundant fraction of the code, one called <x-featured-card> for the first post in the page who has its own design then i created a second component for the rest of the posts called <x-posts-card>, everything works fine untill i decided to replace this whole fraction of the code with another component called <x-posts-grid>, here starts the problem because nothing is rendered on the front page body and when i inspect the page the component is here indeed but the inspector shows 0*0 for the dimensions of the component

,this is the view called post-featured-card which i replaced with the component <x-featured-card>

post-featured-card.blade.php

```
  @props(['post'])

   <article
     class="transition-colors duration-300 hover:bg-gray-100 border border-black border-opacity-0                                                                      hover:border-opacity-5 rounded-xl">
   <div class="py-6 px-5 lg:flex">
         <div class="flex-1 lg:mr-8">
          <img src="/images/illustration-1.png" alt="Blog Post illustration" class="rounded-xl"\>
   </div>

    <div class="flex-1 flex flex-col justify-between">
        <header class="mt-8 lg:mt-0">
            <div class="space-x-2">
                <a href="/categories/{{ $post->category->slug }} " class=" px-3 py-1 border border- blue-300 rounded-full text-blue-300 text-xs uppercase font-semibold" style="font-size: 10px">{{$post->category->name}}</a>
            </div>

            <div class="mt-4">
                <h1 class="text-3xl">
                   <a href = " /posts/{{$post->slug}}">
                       {{ $post->title }}
                   </a>
                </h1>

                <span class="mt-2 block text-gray-400 text-xs">
                        Published <time>{{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</time>
                    </span>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="text-sm mt-2">
            <p>
                {{$post->excerpt}}
            </p>
        </div>

        <footer class="flex justify-between items-center mt-8">
            <div class="flex items-center text-sm">
                <img src="/images/lary-avatar.svg" alt="Lary avatar">
                <div class="ml-3">
                    <h5 class="font-bold">{{$post->author->name}}</h5>
                    <h6>Mascot at Laracasts</h6>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="hidden lg:block">
                <a href="/posts/{{$post->slug}}"
                    class="transition-colors duration-300 text-xs font-semibold bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 rounded-full py-2 px-8"
                >Read More</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>

</article>
```

and this is the view called post-card which i replaced with the component <x-post-card>

post-card.blade.php

```
 @props(['post'])
  <article $attributes->merge(['class'=>'transition-colors duration-300 hover:bg-gray-100 border border-black border-opacity-0 hover:border-opacity-5 rounded-xl'>
<div class="py-6 px-5">
  <div>
  <img src="/images/illustration-3.png" alt="Blog Post illustration" class="rounded-xl">
 </div>

    <div class="mt-8 flex flex-col justify-between">
        <header>
            <div class="space-x-2">
                <x-category-button  :category = "$post->category"/>
            </div>

            <div class="mt-4">
                <h1 class="text-3xl">
                    <a href="/posts/{{$post->slug}}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
                </h1>

                <span class="mt-2 block text-gray-400 text-xs">
                    Published <time>{{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</time>
                </span>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="text-sm mt-4">
            <p>
                {{$post->excerpt}}
            </p>
        </div>

        <footer class="flex justify-between items-center mt-8">
            <div class="flex items-center text-sm">
                <img src="/images/lary-avatar.svg" alt="Lary avatar">
                <div class="ml-3">
                    <h5 class="font-bold">{{$post->author->name}}</h5>
                    <h6>Mascot at Laracasts</h6>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <a href="/posts/{{$post->slug}}"
                    class="transition-colors duration-300 text-xs font-semibold bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 rounded-full py-2 px-8"
                >Read More</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>

</article\>
```

and this is the view post-grid where i grabbed the whole fraction of the code and replaced it with <x-post-grid/> component

post-grid.blade.php

```
   @props(['posts'])
     <x-post-featured-card :post = "$post[0]"/>
     @if($posts->count() > 1)
      <div class="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-6">
     @foreach ($posts->skip(1) as $post)
       <x-post-card    :post = "$post" class = "{{ $loop->iteration < 3 ? 'clos-span-3 ' : 'cols-span-2' }}"/>
      to pass this class here you have to add in the parent tag the
     @endforeach
    </div>
    @endif
```

and this is the posts view where i display the posts

before when it was working regularly

posts.blade.php

```
<x-layout>

    @include('_posts-header')
    <main class="max-w-6xl mx-auto mt-6 lg:mt-20 space-y-6">
        @if($posts->count())
            <x-post-featured-card   :post="$posts[0]"/>
            @if($posts->count()>1)
                <div class="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-2">
                    @foreach($posts->skip(1) as $post)
                          <x-post-card    :post="$post" class = "{{ $loop->iteration < 3 ? 'clos-span-3 ' : 'cols-span-2' }}"/>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endif
        @else
            <p class=" text-center">no posts yet please check back later</p>

        @endif
    </main>


</x-layout>
```

and then after trying the <x-post-grid> component

```
<x-layout>

 @include('_post-header')

<main class="max-w-6xl mx-auto mt-6 lg:mt-20 space-y-6">
    @if ($posts->count())
        <x-post-grid :post = "$post"/>
    @else
        <p class="text-center">No posts yet</p>
    @endif
</main>

</x-layout>
```

i changed the post-grid component name like i found in some forums i tried to change its css by giving it a width and a height but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

You did two things wrong here, please correct it.

1. Passing wrong data to the component i.e. instead of passing `$posts`, you did it with `$post`
2. Declaring attributes incorrectly in calls to components i.e. instead of attributes like `:post="$post"` (without spaces), you did `:post = "$post"` (with spaces)

**posts.blade.php**

```
<x-layout>

    @include('_post-header')

    <main class="max-w-6xl mx-auto mt-6 lg:mt-20 space-y-6">
        @if ($posts->count())
            <x-post-grid :posts="$posts"/>
        @else
            <p class="text-center">No posts yet</p>
        @endif
    </main>

</x-layout>
```

**post-grid.blade.php**

```
@props(['posts'])

<x-post-featured-card :post="$posts[0]"/>

@if($posts->count() > 1)
    <div class="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-6">
        @foreach ($posts->skip(1) as $post)
            <x-post-card :post="$post" class="{{ $loop->iteration < 3 ? 'clos-span-3 ' : 'cols-span-2' }}"/>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: thank you that worked indeed, but now i have a new issue with the merged classes {{$loop->iteration < 3 ? 'cols-span-3' : 'cols-span-2'}} cause they are indeed merged but they don't work no result and i tried to add a ' ! ' in the end of the class like this 'cols-span-3!' before passing it but no result

Comment: @YuriBoyka '!' Always at the beginning of the class and not at the end.
[Important modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier)

Comment: well thank you for that, but it turned out that i didn't need to add that exclamation mark the error was mainly in the tailwind class i was using from the begining it's not 'cols-span-3' it's 'col-span-3' thank you very much for your assistance , appreciate it